# PHPUnit assert mock method with multiple stringContains for one parameter

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Is there a way to assert mocked class method string parameter for multiple matches?

```
$this->getMock()
     ->expects($this->any())
     ->method('setString')
     ->with($this->stringContains('word3'))
     ->will($this->returnSelf());
```

This example will pass for ->setString('word1 word2 word3 word4')

What I need to do is match if setString() is called with parameter containing 'word1' AND 'word3'

But

```
$this->getMock()
     ->expects($this->any())
     ->method('setString')
     ->with(
         $this->stringContains('word1'),
         $this->stringContains('word3')
     )
     ->will($this->returnSelf());
```

this implementation is checking for 2 parameters for setString() and this is not what I have intended to check.

Ideas? using $this->callback() ? Is there some better suited PHPUnit assertions for this?

Comment: This is what helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46922330/470749

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this answer is quite late, but I had the same problem and found a solution that seems to be a little bit smarter... :)

Try this: (untested for your case)

```
$this->getMock()
     ->expects($this->any())
     ->method('setString')
     ->with($this->logicalAnd(
          $this->stringContains('word1'),
          $this->stringContains('word3')
      ))
     ->will($this->returnSelf());
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will do what you're looking for:

```
$this->getMock()
->expects($this->any())
->method('setString')
->with(
    $this->callback(
        function($parameter) {
            $searchWords = array('word1', 'word3');
            $matches     = 0;

            foreach ($searchWords as $word) {
                if (strpos($parameter, $word) !== false) {
                    $matches++;
                }
            }

            if ($matches == count($searchWords)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
))
->will($this->returnSelf());
```

The callback function checks if both values from $searchWords array are part of the first parameter that is passed to setString() method.