# stringContains argument matching within Laravel Log facade shouldReceive

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I saw in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#mocking-facades) that it's possible to set a test expectation like this:

```
Cache::shouldReceive('get')
                ->once()
                ->with('key')
                ->andReturn('value');
```

Then I saw in the [PHPunit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) that flexible argument matching is possible like this: `$this->stringContains('Something')`.

But when I edit my test to have this:

```
Log::shouldReceive('error')
            ->once();
            ->with($this->stringContains('Contact does not exist'));
```

...then I get the following error:

```
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_1_Illuminate_Log_Writer::error("Contact does not exist blah blah etc"). 
Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method
```

How can I accomplish my goal (with flexible argument matching within `Log::shouldReceive`)?

P.S. I've also tried `->with(\PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::stringContains('Contact does not exist'))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mocking functionality of facades uses `Mockery` to generate mock objects. `stringContains()` is functionality provided by PHPUnit mock objects. These two are not compatible.

You will need to use [argument validation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/argument_validation.html) methods provided by Mockery.

My first attempt would be to use the `\Mockery::pattern()` matcher which uses regular expressions:

```
Log::shouldReceive('error')
    ->once()
    ->with(\Mockery::pattern('/Contact does not exist/'));
```

Another option would be to use the `\Mockery::on()` matcher, which allows you to use a Closure to provide complex argument matching logic.

```
Log::shouldReceive('error')
    ->once()
    ->with(\Mockery::on(function ($arg) {
        return stripos($arg, 'Contact does not exist') !== false;
    }));
```

Comment: Wow, I love it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your link to [argument validation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/argument_validation.html) helped in my case, as it was `Mockery::withArgs()` I needed to perform validation for multiple arguments. Thanks

Comment: This helped me again just now. Thanks. I couldn't get `\Mockery::pattern()` working, but `\Mockery::on()` does.

Comment: Wow, I keep coming back to this answer and wish either I could commit this to memory or that many more articles would link here.

Comment: I am getting Mockery::pattern() method not found error. Any ideas? There are other assertions that use Mockery::any() and they all seem to work fine.

Comment: @Ace The `pattern()` method was added in version 1.0. If you're using version 0.9.11 or below, the `pattern()` method will not exist.